# How do I get my code on google sheets to cover multiple tabs?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a code that runs on my google sheets every time someone fills out a form online which pushes info into my CRM Software. It pulls the info in great off of the main tab; but how can I get the script to run for multiple tabs on the same spreadsheet? I tried a couple solutions but couldn't figure it out. this is the current code

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();   
var lastRange = scriptProperties.getProperty("last_range");

//Logger.log("Debug:" + lastRange);

if (!lastRange) {
  var lastRow = sheet.getDataRange().getLastRow() + 1;
  scriptProperties.setProperty("last_range", "A" + lastRow);
  lastRange = scriptProperties.getProperty("last_range");
}

var range = sheet.getRange(lastRange);
var totalRange = sheet.getDataRange();
var isBlank = range.isBlank();
var isGreater = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are currently using:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
```

Where you should be using:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(sheetName);
```

You haven't specified which tabs (sheets) you have, but it should be a simple case of dropping in the appropriate sheet name in the function above.

See https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getSheetByName(String)